# Div Trying To Be Centered But Not Working

Tags: html, css

my problem is that I am trying to center a div inside my full-width header like this:

```
</body>
<!-- the CSS -->
#header {
margin-top: -1em;
margin-left: -1em;
height: 2.95em;
padding:15px 0;
min-width:150%;
background-color: #F4F6F7;
border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;

}
#insideHeader {

border: 1px solid black;
width: 20em;
height: 2.6em;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The result of this code is in the [here](http://jsbin.com/lavawekibi/edit?html,css).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is in centre only but it appears towards right due to horizontal scroll in window. To confirm, change `min-width` value to 100%

Comment: @nikhil thanks but if I do so, there will be white space to right of the header?

Comment: I have added my answer. Please check whether it meets your requirement

Comment: Your width should be 100%, not 150%

Comment: You don't need "min-width" when using percentage. Just use "width: 100%;"

Comment: @JameysonMacDonald Yes, yes, I do. I used it due to finding a website that explains how to make a full header on cross-browsers. If you would like to check it out just press [here](http://www.cssgirl.com/resources/2012/01/15/100-full-width-header-and-footer-with-centered-content-revisited-again/).

Comment: No you don't. max-width is used solely to make something responsive when using pixels. Percent is already responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min-width:100%;` seem to centre your div...

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    margin: 0;
    height: 2.95em;
    padding:15px 0;
    min-width:100%;
    background-color: #F4F6F7;
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}
#insideHeader {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 20em;
    height: 2.6em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="insideHeader"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

or 
http://jsfiddle.net/x1b7zpy4/1/

Comment: this becomes my result: http://jsbin.com/lavawekibi/edit?html,css . I f you pay attention, there is some white space to the right of the div, why is that so?

Comment: this is the auto margin set by jsbin on the virtual `<body>` ; so remove your -1em margin and try on a .html page with your browser ;)

Comment: yes it seems you are correct. I am grateful for your contribution!

Comment: @DiarTurkmani you're welcome, don't forget to check as solved your question ;)

Comment: I have not acquired enough reputation to vote for an answer. XD

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding you are trying to fit the outer box in the window and center align the inner box.

Add/Update following styles

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
  margin-top: -1em;
  height: 2.95em;
  padding:15px 0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #F4F6F7;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}
```

There are default padding/margin of browser. You need to override those in order to fit your outer box.

Once you do that, you need to remove your negative left margins which were put in order to make box stick to the boundary of window.

Then set the width to 100%.

For reference - http://jsbin.com/lomeganori/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: `margin-top: -1em;` => useless no ?

Comment: @Blag - yes seems to be. However, I did not targeted that as that was out of context of this question.

Comment: yes, but as you have removed the `margin-left` I was wondering ; So +1 as you got it in the comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

give

```
   #header
    {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   //and remove height:2.5rem;
   }
```

box-sizing:borderbox will removes all your troubles, and dont give height to parent

that will automatically take the height of the inner div